# Strange structure confusion

Tags: c

Consider the following c code:

```
#define MAX_PROP 16

struct property_setA {
    u32 p1;
    u32 p2;
};

struct property_setB {
    u32 Pg;
};

struct objectA {
    struct property_setA personal_properties [MAX_PROP];
    struct property_setB global_property;
};
```

Now the task is to create a function ***allocate_obj*** which will give some fixed global property (say 32) and initialize the other personal property's memebers (i.e. p1,p2 to 0)
I was able to achieve following code

```
struct objectA* allocate_obj() {
    struct objectA *obj = (struct objectA*)malloc(sizeof(struct objectA);

    // Assign global property
    obj->global_property.Pg = 32;
    // Initialize property_setA fields for this obj


    return obj;
}
```

Here are my doubts:

1. What does personal_properties [MAX_PROP] means. I mean is it saying for every objectA, there will be 16 number of *property_setA* structure will be created or we have to choose the first unused (out of 16) index.
2. If we have to use the first unused, how to get that number. I was trying following for loop (inside allocate_obj()) but it is giving error.

   ```
   u32 i,pd;
   for(i=0;i<MAX_PROP;i++){
    if(obj->personal_properties[i] == NULL){     // This line give error
        pd = i;
        break;
    }
   }
   ```

So how to get the first unused index?

Comment: `obj->personal_properties[i].p1` is an `int` that you can set to any `int` value that you like. It won't ever be NULL, because technically NULL is a pointer, not an `int`.

Comment: `struct property_setA personal_properties [MAX_PROP];` is [an (fixed-size) array declaration](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-array) so my guess is that all the items in the array have to be initialised

Comment: @user3386109 I undestood the error of for loop (as I was comparing structure with NULL) but question of finding min unused index remains

Comment: There is no built-in method to find the min unused index. The two commonly used methods are to add a `first_unused_index` variable to the structure, or fill the array with sentinel values. Note that `malloc` doesn't initialize the array, so if you want to use a sentinel value, you need to fill the array before using it.

Comment: @user3386109 Modifying **structure objectA** is not allowed but other structures and functions can be modified

Comment: Yup, well you really need to **describe the full problem** before anyone can give you a full answer.

Comment: @user3386109 1. This idea of using first unused index is my thinking, it can be wrong and there can be another way . 2. This is the full problem

Comment: According to the question, the task is to set `Pg` to 32, and set all of the `p1` and `p2` values to 0. So no `if` statements, and no `first unused index` are needed.

Comment: @user3386109 how?

Comment: In the class, you were given instruction about **arrays**, and then **structures**, and now **arrays of structures**. If you missed the class about arrays, which seems to be the case, then you're totally lost. You need to go back an learn what you missed. Read the book, talk to a teacher's assistant, talk to your classmates, hire a tutor.

Answer (score 0):

```c
if(obj->property_setA[i] == NULL){     // This line give error
```

This line gives an error because once you index the array, you do not have a pointer (`struct property_setA*`) that you can compare to NULL, you have an actual `struct property_setA`.

You have two options:

1. change the declaration of your array to be an array of pointers:

```c
struct objectA {
    struct property_setA* personal_properties [MAX_PROP];
    struct property_setB global_property;
};

// and then be sure to initialize them all to NULL:
struct objectA* allocate_obj() {
    struct objectA *obj = (struct objectA*)malloc(sizeof(struct objectA);

    memset(obj->personal_properties, 0, sizeof(struct property_setA*) * MAX_PROP);
    // Assign global property
    obj->property_setB.Pg = 32;
    // Initialize property_setA fields for this obj

    return obj;
}
```

Keep in mind in this case you must now `malloc` and `free` the underlying objects when setting/deleting them.

2. Much more simply, add a `used` counter to your structure and keep track manually of how many properties are used:

```
struct objectA {
    size_t used_properties;
    struct property_setA personal_properties [MAX_PROP];
    struct property_setB global_property;
};
```

Initialize it to 0; the next free property is at that index.  When you set a property, increment it (ensuring you don't write past MAX_PROP - 1).

Comment: Modifying **structure objectA** is not allowed but other structures and functions can be modified